# Downloading PDF file with additional data from a Servlet

Tags: java, iphone, servlets

How to download PDF file with other data on the same HTTP request to a Servlet?
For example, I have a PDF file in my server and I want to respond to a request with that PDF file and other data like `myname` and `myage`, etc on the same request. Can it be done on the same request?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of that "other data"? What is the functional requirement? Do you want to refresh the current JSP from where you clicked the download link or something? Or do you want to embed that data in the PDF file itself?

Comment: @BalusC
nope i am downloading pdf file to my iphone with description of pdf file content with that file
I need them to be on the same request,the file and its description

Comment: So, the "other data" is just the filename of the PDF as it should appear in *Save As* dialog?

Comment: @BalusC nope ,I told u file description for example :I have a pdf file named 1234.pdf it contains student grades ... I want the response to have the file and a description about its content which is student grade at the same request

Answer (score 2):

The Java Servlet API does not provide any in-built mechanism for multi-part responses (which is the name of the feature that you are looking for). The Servlet API documentation hints at how this can be achieved, in the [ServletResponse API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html):

> To send binary data in a MIME body
>   response, use the ServletOutputStream
>   returned by getOutputStream(). To send
>   character data, use the PrintWriter
>   object returned by getWriter(). To mix
>   binary and text data, for example, to
>   create a multipart response, use a
>   ServletOutputStream and manage the
>   character sections manually.

Multipart responses are created by setting the content-type (the MIME type) of the response to "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=xyz". The value `xyz` is arbitrary and is used to delineate the several sections of the response. An implementation of a Multipart Response class can be found in the book - ["Java Servlet Programming" by Jason Hunter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/156592391X), and also in the [KickJava site](http://kickjava.com/src/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartResponse.java.htm) (please read the license before using it in your project).

Comment: Can I store my pdf object which is in []bytes in JSON object and return it with response using getWriter();
Like this I mean:
out = response.getPrintWriter();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("name","farajnew");
obj.put("pdffile",fileinbytes);
out.print(obj);
//I know that doesnt work , but cant i use technique like that?

Comment: @farajnew, the last time I checked, any PDF file will contain non-textual information for it contains binary information (fonts, images etc.); I cannot see how you could store it in a JSON object unless you encode it into a textual representation.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds 
I saw this but i am using different library ,
http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONSerializer.html#toJSON(java.lang.Object)
can this work?

Comment: what i am searching .... can i serialize the pdf file and send it in JSON object and the JSONobject can be send to client?

Comment: @farajnew, no, I don't think so. Mapping the contents of a PDF file to a JSON object is not a trivial exercise, unless you have a set of Java classes and objects representing the PDF file. You might want to encode the sequence of bytes (which is my assumption) representing the PDF file, using Base64 or any other encoding scheme that will give you a set of characters (which could then be placed in a JSON response).

Comment: Thank you very much , i guess this might solve it , or as the other response i can put the information in the response header ?

Answer (score 0):

If this other data is just text, perhaps you could it include it as headers of the response

Comment: can i put a small JSON object in header?
it contains only 4 keys max?

Comment: You could put 4 headers, with names prefixed with X-, as Wikipedia says it is conventional: [List_of_HTTP_header_fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) (Common non-standard headers)

Comment: By the way: It seems that somebody already thought to put JSON-encoded data in the headers: http://deadlytechnology.com/scripts/return-json-array-using-ajax-and-prototype/